# Can't start Zoom on Windows

Tags: zoom-meeting

I am not able to start Zoom on Windows. When I click on the app in start menu, Zoom window doesn't open. The system tray icon is also not there. All I can see is a new process in Task Manager.

I've tried reinstalling the app, but it didn't help. This has been going on for 3 weeks now. It was working fine before that.

Can I get some advice on how to get Zoom up and running again?

Thanks.

Comment: Does it work with another user? If so you may need to remove the Zoom's settings folder of your current user. Reinstalling doesn't do that.

Comment: Also, uninstall Zoom completely (Programs and Features), restart and install it again.